# In the English law, how is a conflict of interest between an extradition request and a criminal conviction solved?

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom, extradition

This question was motivated by Julian Assange's famous case, but it is a more general question.

As it is [known](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/julian-assange-prison-jail-time-weeks-bail-embassy-a8894326.html?amp), he currently has a conviction of 50 weeks prison term for bail jumping. Thus, England wants him to serve it in a prison (jail?).

From the other side, another country - this time, the USA - wants him, without a conviction (in the USA), but because also they want to punish him.

Thus, we have a conflict of interest:

1. The English criminal system wants him to serve his punishment. They are probably tuned to not allow him to go to anywhere, until he served his prison term.
2. Also the criminal system of another country wants him. The U.K. is bound by international agreements to give him to them.

The logical solution would be to first make him to serve his punishment in the U.K., and then extradict him to the USA. It seems a likely outcome in JA's case, but not always.

For example, in the case of a famous terrorist or war criminal, it would be surreal to delay his criminal procedure, only because he committed also some traffic offense in the U.K.

Which interest will be stronger? How is it being decided?

Comment: Please note: this is the *law*.stackexchange.com, extra-legal options/possibilities are here *per definitionem* off-topic. I tried to formulate the question to the objective, legal part and please follow this also in the answers/comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they just wait until he has served his time in most cases.

The United Kingdom and the United States can agree that he can serve the time in the United States though.

Comment: Ok, but how is it being decided, what will happen? The UK judge can only determine, is he guilty or not, and what will be his punishment. Somehow a mechanism should exist, what arbitrates the contradicting interests, how does it work?

Comment: Its not really contradicting, tbh. They would literally call the U.S. on the phone when hes done there or just say him awaiting trial in the U.S. counts as his punishment.

Comment: Yes, obviously these are the options, but who decides it and how is it being decided? What is the case in the other example case (serious offender committed also a light offense in the UK, serving the punishment for the light case that would delay the criminal procedure in the serious case)

Comment: Either the judge will say it is ok if he serves his punishment in the U.S. then he gets picked up or when he is done there the jail would literally call the U.S.

Comment: Not to sound rude, but there's just not anything more. Instead of the jail releasing him they give him to the U.S. whenever his release would be. I don't know exactly when he gets released.

Comment: Thus, the power of the judge is actually more than determining his guilt and punishment, he can also affect, how the UK will keep/delay/reject his obligations in an international treaty? My impression is, that such a decision could be over the effect of a "simple" UK criminal judge.

Comment: Yeah the judge just presides over the trial and sentences you. Extradition is just putting him on the plane or whatever then he goes to the U.S.

Comment: The extradition treaty between the UK and the US has probably an "implementation" in the local law of both countries. I.e. it is somewhere prescribed for the judge, and for the whole criminal system, how should they balance an extradition request and a local punishment. The essence of the question is the details of this mechanism, not only the possible outcomes.

Comment: Ok, I believe you! So it is the decision of the judge? (Btw, sorry for the offtopic question: doing this work means, that you need to seriously harm others regularly, based on the written law and not on your best conscience. Isn't it depressing a little bit? What if you need to extradict or send into jail someone, while you think he doesn't deserve it?)

Comment: The decision of the judge is just for whether the punishment is served at the same time as the punishment in the other jurisdiction which would mean that you can be sent there before your punishment is over.

Comment: But 99% of the time, you are ordered to be in jail until date x. Then on date x instead of having a friend come pick you up, a law enforcement officer is at the door.

Comment: There's defiantly innocent people who go to jail, its not good, but there's not always something you can do.

Comment: Also, the court gets involved when you contest extradition. That is the most common reason for the judge to get involved.